# Tengo una duda respecto al programa que no ejecuta todo el código

Tags: python-3.x

La verdad tengo la duda cuando pruebo el programa solo me pregunta el numero y nada más y no sé qué hacer.

```
print ("Seleccione 1 para Registrar Persona, ingrese 2 para Solicitar Acceso")

Opt = input("Ingrese el numero de la opción requerida: ")

if Opt == 1:

    class Persona:
           def __init__ (self, Rut, PNombre, SNombre, APaterno, AMaterno, CAcceso):
       
        self.Rut = Rut
        self.PNombre = PNombre
        self.SNombre = SNombre
        self.APaterno = APaterno
        self.AMaterno = AMaterno
        self.CAcceso = CAcceso
    
    def MostarInfo(self):
        return '{} {} {} {} {} {}'.format(self.Rut,self.PNombre,self.SNombre,self.APaterno,self.AMaterno,self.CAcceso)

    R = input("Ingrese su rut: ")
    PN = input("Ingrese su nombre: ")
    SN = input("Ingrese su segundo nombre: ")
    AP = input("Ingrese su primer apellido: ")
    AM = input("Ingrese su segundo apellido: ")
    CA = input("Ingrese su clave se acceso: ")

    Answer = Persona(R,PN,SN,AP,AM,CA)
        
    print(Answer.Mostrarinfo())
```

Comment: estas llamando al metodo `Answer.Mostrarinfo` y es `MostrarInfo` *Info* con mayúscula

Answer (score 1):

Haber tienes varios errores, en primer lugar tu input te devuelve un strrig y estas comparando con un entero y no se cumplirá la condición por lo que no se creará la clase `Persona`, en segundo lugar estas llamando al método `Mostrarinfo` y es `MostrarInfo`(Info con mayúscula)

Otra cosa, es recomendable crear la clase afuera de cualquier bloque y luego solo instanciarla cuando sea necesario.

Con todo lo que expliqué tu código debería quedar así:

```py
class Persona:
    def __init__ (self, Rut, PNombre, SNombre, APaterno, AMaterno, CAcceso):
        self.Rut = Rut
        self.PNombre = PNombre
        self.SNombre = SNombre
        self.APaterno = APaterno
        self.AMaterno = AMaterno
        self.CAcceso = CAcceso

    def MostarInfo(self):
        #utilizamos f-stings
        return f'\nDatos\nRut:{self.Rut}\nNombre completo:{self.PNombre} {self.SNombre}\nApellidos:{self.APaterno} {self.AMaterno}\nAccesso:{self.CAcceso}'

print("Seleccione 1 para Registrar Persona, ingrese 2 para Solicitar Acceso")

Opt = int(input("Ingrese el numero de la opción requerida: ")) #convertimos a entero

if Opt == 1:
    R = input("Ingrese su rut: ")
    PN = input("Ingrese su nombre: ")
    SN = input("Ingrese su segundo nombre: ")
    AP = input("Ingrese su primer apellido: ")
    AM = input("Ingrese su segundo apellido: ")
    CA = input("Ingrese su clave se acceso: ")

    Answer = Persona(R,PN,SN,AP,AM,CA)
        
    print(Answer.MostarInfo()) #llamamos correctamente al metodo
```

**resultado**

```
Seleccione 1 para Registrar Persona, ingrese 2 para Solicitar Acceso
Ingrese el numero de la opción requerida: 1
Ingrese su rut: 990
Ingrese su nombre: christian
Ingrese su segundo nombre: naokiri
Ingrese su primer apellido: velasquez
Ingrese su segundo apellido: B.
Ingrese su clave se acceso: 999900

Datos
Rut:990
Nombre completo:christian naokiri
Apellidos:velasquez B.
Accesso:999900
```

Como detalle es que si el usuario  no ingresa un numero, el programa lanzará una excepción, puedes prevenirlo con un `try/except` o haciendo la comparación con un string (en ese caso ya no conviertas a entero)

Comment: Es una buena opción convertir Opt en int.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando recibes de un input, el dato es de tipo string, así que cuando pides seleccionar opción 1 o 2, realmente lo que ingresa es '1' o '2'. Verifica con el type para que te des cuenta. EN el código la clase debe estar fuera. El código quedaría así:

```
print ("Seleccione 1 para Registrar Persona, ingrese 2 para Solicitar Acceso")

Opt = input("Ingrese el numero de la opción requerida: ")
print(type(Opt)) #Esto verifica el tipo de entrada
class Persona:
  def __init__ (self, Rut, PNombre, SNombre, APaterno, AMaterno, CAcceso):

        self.Rut = Rut
        self.PNombre = PNombre
        self.SNombre = SNombre
        self.APaterno = APaterno
        self.AMaterno = AMaterno
        self.CAcceso = CAcceso
if Opt == '1': #Aqui la opción es como string órque eso es lo que arroja el input
    print('estoy dentro') # Esto verifica si ha entrado al if
    R = input("Ingrese su rut: ")
    PN = input("Ingrese su nombre: ")
    SN = input("Ingrese su segundo nombre: ")
    AP = input("Ingrese su primer apellido: ")
    AM = input("Ingrese su segundo apellido: ")
    CA = input("Ingrese su clave se acceso: ")
    
    def MostarInfo(self):
        return '{} {} {} {} {} {}'.format(self.Rut,self.PNombre,self.SNombre,self.APaterno,self.AMaterno,self.CAcceso)
    Answer = Persona(R,PN,SN,AP,AM,CA)
    print(Answer.MostrarInfo())
```